# Cannot get tar file command to work on ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, tar

I have been trying to run this command `tar -xvf bomb3_stu.tar` on my schools ssh for hours and it keeps giving me errors like

```
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I'm tired and lost and maybe stupid but I don't know what to do and this is due tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

That error usually suggests an I/O problem. First, make sure you have the correct path, and that there isn't a .gz or other extension on the end.

```
$ ls -l ipmi.tar 
-rw-r--r--. 1 <myuser> <mygroup> <myfilesize> <datestamp> ipmi.tar
```

Second, make sure it's an actual tar file. You should get output like this:

```
$ file ipmi.tar 
ipmi.tar: POSIX tar archive (GNU)
```

Third, make sure you are extracting it in a directory that you have write privileges to. You want to see the 'w' as per output below.

```
$ ls -ld .
drwx------. 1 <myuser> <mygroup> 886 Mar  3 17:43 ./
```

Fourth, look inside and make sure the tar file expects to write in the current directory.

```
$ tar -tf ipmi.tar
./IPMIView_2.13.0_build.170504_bundleJRE_Linux_x64/
./IPMIView_2.13.0_build.170504_bundleJRE_Linux_x64/lax.jar
./IPMIView_2.13.0_build.170504_bundleJRE_Linux_x64/iKVM.jar
```